# Breakpoints being ignored

Tags: .net, c++-cli

First time using C++/CLI.

I am attaching to my process, my DLL is being loaded and is running.  But my breakpoints are being ignored.

Is there anything special that needs to be configured when attaching to a process and debugging using C++/CLI?  The application is native.  My DLL has been compiled using the /clr option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you attach, in the "Attach to Process" dialog, you'll see an "Attach to:" which indicates what type of code you're going to Debug.  Click the "Select" button and choose all the code types you want to debug.

You'll probably want to select both Managed and Native.